# (Django) How do I make the 'selected' option valid after altering a foreign key drop-down?

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

I have a model whose fields are a date and a foreign key to another model's text field:

```
# models.py
class Publications(models.Model):
    """A class for daily article publications"""

    date = models.DateField(
        help_text="date for this article to be published"
    )
    headline = models.ForeignKey(
        Articles,
        help_text='The article to be published, represented by its headline'
    )
```

On the Admin 'Add' page for that model, I've added Javascript so that when I select a date from the calendar selector widget for `date`, the drop-down selector for the Articles FK is automatically restricted to the subset of Articles ready for publication on that day.  This is accomplished by clearing the drop-down selector and then re-filling it with the results of an AJAX call to a backend view:

```
// Javascript for Publications "Add" admin page
// Grab the Article <select> element
let artSelect = document.getElementById("id_headline");

// Clear it
artSelect.innerHTML = '';

// Fill it with new <option> elements from 'data', a list of Article
// headlines retrieved via AJAX
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = data[i];
    // If it's the first option, make it 'selected'
    if (i == 0) {
        opt.setAttribute("selected", "");
    }
    artSelect.appendChild(opt);
}
```

If, after selecting a date and watching the headline drop-down be filtered accordingly, I select one of the filtered set of headlines, I can select "Save" and the Publications entry (date and Article FK) will be saved to the database successfully.

The problem I've encountered is that if I don't manually select an Article from the drop-down after filtering by date -- for example, if the first headline showing in the new, filtered drop-down is the one I want -- and I try to select Save, the page reloads with a prompt to "Please correct the error below" and an error over the headline drop-down "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."  The behavior is unique to the first option, the one shown by default; it happens even if I open the drop-down and manually click on that option, and it happens whether or not I give it the 'selected' attribute.  As I mentioned above, if I open the drop-down and select any other option, the page works fine.

I've traced the error message to the `ModelChoiceField()` class of `django/forms/models.py` in the main Django installation.  However, I'm not sure where to go from here.  Not only do I not want to change a file in Django itself, I don't know how I would.  I can't figure out what changes I can make within my own app to make the default Article selection valid.

One guess I can make is that the Admin is programmed to always treat the first value in a FK drop-down as a placeholder option, like "-----".  Is this true, and is there a way to disable it with a setting in my App's `admin.py`?  I tried looking for documenation about this, but I couldn't find any.

Otherwise, how do I make the default selection of a Foreign-Key dropdown a "valid choice" after altering the dropdown contents?

**EDIT:** I've decided it's better UX to leave the first option as a non-valid option that indicates what filtering has been done, so this question is moot for my purposes.  However, I think the underlying question of "Does the Django Admin always treat the first value in a FK drop-down as a placeholder option, and is there a way to disable it?" is a good question, so I'm leaving this open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is quite the subtle: you set the value of the first option to 0. Foreign keys start at 1... So an option value of 0 can never be in the Model choices. And you'll probably find that selected articles do not correspond with the titles (or only by chance).

You should present a list of 2-tuples to your ajax (or objects with 'id' and 'title) and then create opt.value = data.id.

Comment: I've confirmed this is correct by testing.  Good thing I left the question open!